# How to dispose of System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer

Tags: c#

The question is simple and can be summed up by:

How can I get this while loop to exit?

```
System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer player = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
WeakReference test = new WeakReference(player);

player.Close();
player = null;

while (test.IsAlive && test.Target != null)
{
    System.GC.Collect();
}
```

I have searched the documentation and have found no way to dispose of this object, the while loop never exits.

Comment: What's wrong with letting GC dispose it internally? It looks like `MediaPlayer` is not an `IDisposable` object so you don't have to worry about manually disposing of it.

Comment: This will be a hold-and-catch-fire loop when you debug your code.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034) explains why.  Stop helping.

Comment: I am debugging a memory leak where MediaPlayer objects are never disposed of.  I can't guarantee that references no longer exist but I'm pretty sure they don't so I was trying to devise a test to prove that there is nothing special about them.  I was using the WeakReference to test whether they have been disposed of but that wasn't working either.  How else can I verify that an object has been disposed of?

Comment: Well, not this way.   This code doesn't leak of course.  When you post fake code that doesn't have anything to do with your real program then nobody can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised that neither the C# documentation nor the Java documentation describes it that clearly:

If there is no memory pressure, a WeakReference will not be collected.

This [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article might be helpful:

> A weak reference **permits** the garbage collector to collect the object while still allowing the application to access the object.

Permission is not a requirement. It may do so, but it needn't.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference#Variations) gets it right under *Variations* (for Java, but Java and C# are quite similar):

> [...] the GC may decide not to do so if it believes the JVM can spare the memory (e.g. the JVM has lots of unused heap space)

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to force the collection?

Comment: @SidG. Get rid of all references, including the weak reference. Then call `GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);` and `GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(100);` (no guarantee that this works). After that, create a full memory dump. Analyze the dump and find out why the MediaPlayer objects are still rooted (in WinDbg `!dumpheap -type MediaPlayer` and `!gcroot` are a starting point).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, at least this gets me closer and explains the answer to my original question.